# Need help to create payments in Invoice Manager

Tags: extensions, joomla-3.6

I'm considering buying this software and I went to its demo, but can't figure out myself how to break a total sum into payments. For example, my client owes me $300, okay? He can pay me $150 and then again $150. Let's say the first payment can be paid on June 1, 2020 till June 5, 2020 and the 2nd one from July 1, 2020 till July 5, 2020. So 5th of July is a due date for the whole invoice. What is a "Due date" for a payment and what is a "Payment daytime"? What's the difference? I don't understand the terminology behind it....In my particular example, what exactly must be done? I create two payments for $150 each. But which "Due date" and "Payment daytime" would be in that case?
I'll attach a screenshot to make things clearer.[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer for some pre-sales analysis before purchasing?

Comment: I've tried, but it takes them time to answer...